# checkbox/toggle button check/uncheck itself

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, togglebutton

I have a number of checkboxes that I want to handle them as toggle buttons. Each one is totally independent from the other and can be either checked or unchecked. When the user clicks on the checkbox/button it stays checked and if the user clicks again, then the checkbox/button returns to the "unchecked" state. Can the checkbox/button check/uncheck itself?

I have been trying for a long time, searching also in the internet and cannot find a solution.

Comment: `Can the checkbox/button check/uncheck itself?`. Explain it.

Comment: Need some example code ... I am not understanding what have your tried ?

Comment: Have you tried to implement checked change event of checkbox? On this event you will get that whether it is checked or unchecked.

Comment: If the "toggle" button is checked and I click it, it becomes unchecked. And vice versa.

Comment: What's a "toggle" button? Checkboxes check and uncheck when you click them.

Comment: Yes, I have used the checkedChange event.

Comment: `private void toggButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            switch(toggButton.CheckState)
            {
                case CheckState.Checked:
                    toggButton.Checked = !toggButton.Checked;                        
                break;
}
`
This is the code that I want to implement...

Comment: The question is not descriptive enough and makes to many assumptions that we know the context you are working on please explain more

Comment: @user1304490: Without implementing `CheckedChanged`, the checkbox will check and uncheck when it's clicked. Also, `ToggleButton` is WPF, not Windows Forms.

Comment: The problem is that the checkbox/button is "displayed" as always pressed i.e. the "blue" color that it has when checked is not changed giving the impression that it is not unchecked.

Comment: Please clarify the question - in particular, clearly describe the behavior you expect.

Comment: I am using WinForms. 
I want to create a button that when clicked stays clicked. And if clicked again it returns to "unclicked" state. So it "toggles" between two states: clicked->unclicked->clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Check the status of the check box, every time the button is clicked, change it.

```
private void toggButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // everytime you click the button checkbox states will change.
    if(checkBox.Checked)
    {
        checkBox.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
       checkBox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the checkbox/button is "displayed" as always
>   pressed i.e. the "blue" color that it has when checked is not changed
>   giving the impression that it is not unchecked. – user1304490

May be setting [CheckBox.ThreeState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.threestate.aspx) property false helps.

If the ThreeState property is set to false, the CheckState property value can only be set to the Indeterminate value of System.Windows.Forms.CheckState in code and not by user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

A very short command:

```
checkBox.Checked = !checkBox.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a common event to all Checkboxes. Write this code in your .cs file and select all Checkboxes and assign this event to checkedChange event.

```
private void chkboxes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    if(!chk.Checked)
        chk.Checked = true;
    else
        chk.Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [CheckBox.CheckState](http://www.google.co.in/gwt/x?wsc=hg&wsi=51573f8fca08bc22&source=m&u=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate.aspx&ei=bG6oT9ONF-uviQeZqtDkAw) property.
it is read and write property so you set it in GUI or through code.

**Checked** The CheckBox displays a check mark. The control appears sunken.
**Unchecked** The CheckBox is empty. The control appears raised.
 **Indeterminate** The CheckBox displays a check mark and is shaded. The control appears flat.

write this on checked change event and check it is toggle or not..    *it will work as like a switch..*

```
    label1.Text = "ThreeState: " + checkBox1.ThreeState.ToString() + "\n" + "Checked: " + 
checkBox1.Checked.ToString() + "\n" + "CheckState: " + checkBox1.CheckState.ToString();
```

for your question's answer check [CheckBox.AutoCheck Property](http://www.google.co.in/gwt/x?source=m&u=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.autocheck.aspx&wsi=51573f8fca08bc22&ei=-22oT6blCsGeiQfq5cXqAQ&wsc=hg)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change check box state for too many check boxes on one form, you need fast reliable code, without complexity.

The best way for doing it is using:

> CheckBox.CheckState

you can change Check Boxes state to (unchecked) for example using this code:

```
checkbox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
checkbox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
checkbox3.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
```

For further reading, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear but if someone is still struggling with checkboxes:

Toggle between two of them(both checkboxes cannot be ticked at the same time and min. one need to be ticked):

```
 private void chkBoxON_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkBoxON.Checked)
        {
            chkBoxOFF.Checked = false;
            // here some code to do after this checkbox is ticked
        }
        else
        {
            chkBoxOFF.Checked = true;
        }
        
    }

    private void chkBoxOFF_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkBoxOFF.Checked)
        {
            chkBoxON.Checked = false;
            // here some code to do after this checkbox is ticked
        }
        else
        {
            chkBoxON.Checked = true;
        }
        
    }
```

If you need only one checked or both unchecked then:

```
 if (chkBoxON.Checked)
        {
            chkBoxOFF.Checked = false;
        }
    }

    private void chkBoxOFF_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkBoxOFF.Checked)
        {
            chkBoxON.Checked = false; 
        }
```

If you need to change the state of it using the button then:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chkBoxON.Checked = false;
        //chkBoxON.Checked = true; //if need to be checked
    }
```

If you need to disable the possibility to click checkBox then:

```
chkBoxOFF.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to use the NOT operator to create the simplest toggle.

```
checkBox.Checked = !checkBox.Checked;
```

Comment: It is not useful, nor in keeping with community guidelines, to post an answer that is essentially an exact duplicate of [another answer that already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28085905).

Comment: Thanks, I’ll keep that in mind in the future. I didn’t notice the same exact answer originally and then was surprised it had no up votes because I think this is the simplest answer. I also think it’s not always a well known convention and was not obvious from the comments in the other post that I also wanted to clarify that the NOT operator is used if it wasn’t obvious or apparent.